# VBA (Word) method workbook of object chartdata failed

Tags: .net, vba, charts, ms-word

I think I encountered a bug in VBA for word 2013 and I'd like to find a workaround. In the following example, there is one button to create a graph, and one button to add data to it. The code works fine until the a file with a graph is saved and then loaded again. Then, CommandButton2_Click() gives the error: "method workbook of object chartdata failed".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim chartWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim salesChart As Word.Chart
    Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    For Each objShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If objShape.HasChart Then
            With objShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
                .ListObjects("Table1").Resize .Range("A1:B10")
                For i = 1 To 10
                    .Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = CStr(i)
                    .Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = CStr(10 * i)
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The code is based on [Microsoft's own example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff629397(v=office.14).aspx) and I've tried to take into account some solutions from Stack Overflow but they do not solve the problem. I Hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not a bug. ChartData must be Activated before you use it. Otherwise, bad things happen.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim chartWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim salesChart As Word.Chart
    Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart


  End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        For Each objShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If objShape.HasChart Then
'----------------------------------------- the bugfix ----------------------
                objShape.Chart.ChartData.Activate 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                With objShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
                    .ListObjects("Table1").Resize .Range("A1:B10")
                    For i = 1 To 10
                        .Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = CStr(i)
                        .Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = CStr(10 * i)
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Hope it helps someone!